# Django raw SQL in optimization?

Tags: python, django

I think my code is not very pythonic ，How to optimize？

code

```
lamp_keys=["ids"]
if len(lamp_keys) == 1:
    rsql = f"""
                SELECT * from brelation
                where source_key = '{lamp_keys[0]}' and target_concept='aaa'
            """
else:
    rsql = f"""
                SELECT * from brelation
                where source_key in {tuple(lamp_keys)} and target_concept='aa'
            """
robjs = RelationModel.objects.raw(rsql)
```

if lame_keys length is 1, if use in must be error, for example:

```
SELECT * from `brelation` WHERE source_key in ('xx',) and target_concept='aa'
```

Comment: Note: The way you write queries you are **vulnerable to SQL injection**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make the very dangerous mistake of formatting raw SQL yourself. Suppose in the part:

```
where source_key = '{lamp_keys[0]}'
```

Some user decides they want to be malicious and gives some value like `'; DROP TABLE brelation; --` for `lamp_keys[0]` you can imagine what might happen yes? Your table will get dropped! This is called **SQL Injection**.

When you want to use some user defined value in a raw query always use parameterized queries. Reference: [Passing parameters into raw() [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw):

```
rsql = f"SELECT * from brelation where source_key in %s and target_concept='aaa'"
robjs = RelationModel.objects.raw(rsql, [lamp_keys])
```

Moving further it doesn't look like you even need to use raw queries, something like below would be equivalent to your raw query:

```
robjs = RelationModel.objects.filter(source_key__in=lamp_keys, target_concept='aaa')
```